# How to count grouped negative values by year

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data set of prices in which the first column is year and the rest of the columns are regions.  I'm trying to count the number of negative values by year by region.

I've tried to use `dplyr` to `group_by(year)` then `summarise_at()` but I can't figure out the exact code to use.

```
Neg_Count <- select (BaseCase, Year, 'Hub1': 'Hub15')
Neg_Count <- Neg_Count %>%
  group_by(Year) %>%
```

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `summarise_at`.  Create a logical vector and get the `sum`

```
library(dplyr)
Neg_Count %>%
      group_by(Year) %>%
       summarise_at(vars(starts_with("Hub")), ~ sum(. < 0))
```